# jsoup Parsing HTML inside async task Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML using `jsoup` Parser for Android.

If I run my code, I'm unable to get into the for loop; program execution is stopping before the for loop (No error is output).

I had put Log? The same code when I run in normal java project I'm able to get the result?

```
private class DownloadTwitterTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
        String content;

        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {


            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com/someperson/").get();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("Exception", "Exception");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class",
                    "js-tweet-text tweet-text");


            for (int j=0;j<elements.size();j++) {


                Element tmp = elements.get(j);
                String value = tmp.text();

                twitterList.add(value);

            }

            return twitterList;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {

            tadaptor = new TwitterLazyAdaptor(INFOActivity.this, result);
            // this.setListAdapter(fadaptor);
            lv1.setAdapter(tadaptor);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `elements` is just empty?

Comment: So then there is nothing to loop and you wont get into your `for` :)

Comment: But i'm getting the element values ,if i run in normal java project

Comment: Maybe the twitter link redirects you to a different mobile site :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
doc.select(".js-tweet-text.tweet-text")
```

The . at the beginning for class, and the . before "tweet-text" for the space.

**Update:**
I compared my solution to yours. It gives the same result.

You can try to set the user agent also. Sometimes a site gives back significantly different html.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com/someperson/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0")
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check also if "doc" is empty. If it is empty, maybe there is something wrong with the connection. You can also do selection like this 
`Elements elements = doc.select("p.js-tweet-text tweet-text");` where "p" is tag that you looking and then class attribute. Also have you set 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and where do you execute `DownloadTwitterTask`